# ¿Como saber el indíce de una linea de archivo?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Escribir la función encuentraLineas(nomArch,palabra) que recibe el nombre de un archivo y una palabra. Esta función devuelve una lista con los números de líneas en la que está presente la palabra:

el ejemplo:
uso de la función con la palabra salud
Lineas palabra salud: [7, 21, 23, 26]
uso de la función con la palabra nutrición
Lineas palabra nutrición: [7, 23]

lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
for linea in file:
  palabra = (input('Escribre la palabra :'))
  if palabra in linea:
    print(linea.index(palabra))
```

Comment: Si usas `for num, linea in enumerate(file, start=1):`, tendrás en `num` el número de línea.

Answer (score 1):

Usando comprensión de listas:

```
def encuentraLineas(nomArch, palabra):
    with open(nomArch, 'r') as f:
        res = [numero for numero, linea in enumerate(f.readlines(), start=1) if palabra in linea]
    return res
```

La comprensión es un `for` más conciso. Lo especial es el uso de `enumerate`. Esta función recibe un iterador, que en este caso es `f.readlines()`. Por cada elemento del iterador, `enumerate` devuelve un contador y el elemento en cuestión.

No estamos interesados en el elemento en si; sólo en el contador, que vamos agregando a la lista.

#### Demo

Con El Quijote de La Mancha como texto (Proyecto Gutenberg), obtenemos:

```
def encuentraLineas(nomArch, palabra):
    with open(nomArch, 'r') as f:
        res = [numero for numero, linea in enumerate(f.readlines(), start=1) if palabra in linea]
    return res

print(encuentraLineas("/home/candid/PycharmProjects/pandas/quijote.txt", "hidalgo"))
```

produce:

```
[2, 8, 32, 43, 90, 340, 445, 569, 574, 578, 587, 595, 1462, 1498, 1508, 1588, 2308, 2364, 3138, 3859, 3975, 4135, 4305, 8750, 8891, 9953, 9962, 15549, 16535, 16557, 16585, 17671, 18327, 18380, 18404, 18408, 18409, 19301, 19655, 21764, 21786, 21789, 21796, 21806, 21839, 21878, 21905, 21936, 21981, 22020, 22030, 22035, 22047, 22076, 22078, 22104, 22185, 24156, 25215, 25759, 26085, 26106, 26114, 26120, 26131, 26132, 26135, 26548, 26884, 26887, 29220, 29239, 30329, 30515, 30735, 31463, 33104, 36173]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que recorrer linea por línea y verificar en cada una si existe la palabra. Por cada línea recorrida, se irá sumando 1 a un acumulador que será el índice:

```
def encuentraLineas(nomArch, palabra):
    res = []
    i = 0
    with open(nomArch, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            if palabra in line:
                res.append(i)
    return res
```

Un ejemplo de ejecución:

**test.txt**

> Linea 1
> Linea 2 salud 2
> Linea 3
> Linea 4 Salud
> Linea 5 salud, salud, 350
> Fin del archivo

```
print(encuentraLineas('test.txt', 'salud')) 
# Imprime como resultado: [2, 5]
```

[+] Para que sea insensible a mayúsculas, en la función modificar el `if` así:

```
if palabra.lower() in line.lower():
```